# Can I still use smart_banner in XML?

Tags: java, android, admob

The admob smart_banner is deprecated in java code. But it isn't mark as deprecated in XML.

my xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My java:

```
    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My question here is, will smart_banner work? Do I have to change my ads code? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Accordingly](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/smart)  you are not doing anything wrong , smart banner ads are valid ads size ,but the site says you should rather use [Adaptive Banner](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive#java) which change the banner size accordingly and are more preferred .

> Adaptive banners are the next generation of responsive ads, maximizing
> performance by optimizing ad size for each device. Improving on smart
> banners, which only supported fixed heights, adaptive banners let
> developers specify the ad-width and use this to determine the optimal
> ad size.

Your java code  shows `AdSize.SMART_BANNER` deprecated  because the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize) says to [use](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize#public-static-adsize-getcurrentorientationanchoredadaptivebanneradsize-context-context,-int-width)

`public static AdSize getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize (Context context, int width)`
instead of `AdSize.SMART_BANNER` , it returns an AdSize with the given width and a Google-optimized height to create a banner ad | this dosen't happens in xml as there's no alternative way also you should use Adaptive Banners which works in simillar ways .

If you **want** to use it you can use this way of setting adSize

```
AdSize adSize = getAdSize();
adView.setAdSize(adSize);
```

and get adSize() as

```
private AdSize getAdSize() { 
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
 float widthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels; 
float density = outMetrics.density; int adWidth = (int) (widthPixels / density);

 return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is when I set in JAVA: `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);` it says it is deprecated. But in XML it says nothing.